# VS Tests run locally but aren't found on the build server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, azure-pipelines

I've got a project that I'm trying to create a build definition for in VSTS. The goal is to build the project, run all the unit tests, then publish if they pass. Tests are via Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting, and locally, everything works fine - VS 2015 discovers and runs all the tests without a hitch.

However, something's going wrong in the build definition. Steps:

1. Run `dotnet restore`.
2. Build Solution `**\*.sln`.
3. Run `dotnet publish`.
4. Test Assemblies `**\$(BuildConfiguration)\**\*Test*.dll`.
5. Remaining publish logic.

Everything seems to run fine on the VSTS build, until step 4:

`Warning: No test is available in C:\agent\_work\19\s\test\Foo.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\Foo.Test.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.`

Test files look something like this:

```
namespace Foo.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ServiceTests
    {
        public ServiceTests()
        {

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void RequestSuccessfullyAddsFilter()
        {
            ...
```

So, what could be stopping the build definition from finding the tests? It's finding the dll, I don't have any unusual parameters set in the test assemblies step. This seems like a pretty cut-and-dry setup, but there must be some step I'm overlooking in here.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution from one of my teammates - it's a .NET Core project, so switching the test task over to the dotnet test task resolved the issue.